# Synchronize Templates with Search and Replace

Tags: expressionengine

When I do search and replace text in my Expressionengine templates, using the "Tools > Data > Search and Replace" it doesn't synch with the files.

Has anyone else had this? I guess not a big problem as can easily do a search and replace in the files too.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the Synchronize Templates tool (In the Design->Templates menu) to synchronize the templates?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get lots of green tick marks to say they are synched, but they're not.

Comment: You're right - it doesn't synch the other way. From the Synchronize templates page: "Selected templates will be updated to match the current associated file."

Comment: I guess they assume that if you store templates as files, you won't search and replace from the CP (easier to do directly in the files). I wish EE would just use the database OR files though, keeping both in sync is a nightmare.

Comment: Note to self: only search and replace in files. I always 'save template as files' so makes sense for me. I agree, having a choice would be good, although Snippets can't save as files, unless using Low Variable.

Comment: @Samsull You can save snippets (and global vars, templates, etc) as files in various ways: Snippet Sync, LibrarEE, SnippetsSync and MountEE